# Pointer or reflect to the object in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry my question is not clear, so i edit it again:

I use window form visual studio desginer, and make a group of n button that they have same action, so my code look like:

```
void main()
{
   f1();
   f2();
   ...
   fn();
}

void f1()
{
    button1.Enable = true;
}

void f2()
{
    button2.Enable = true;
}
...
void fn()
{
    buttonn.Enable = true;
}
```

I wanna to change the code for easy to control and edit with the same action button like:

```
void main()
{
   for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
      f(i);
}

void f(int i)
{
   button[i].Enable = true;
}
```

But i dont know how to implement the function f.

I can make list of button, and manual init it, but it will lost the VS auto designer. I just want to use the group of button from the designer and call it by counter parameter.

Could anyone suggest me the idea,  or code please? thanks for reading

Comment: How is `buttonlist` defined/initialized?  How might you do so such that it contains the four buttons from your first code snippet?

Comment: my code just example, i dont know how to implement my ideas, that why i asking. i   have a group button name with same action , and it have counter like 1,2,3,4... i just find the way to do the code same with all of them by the counter, not call all of them, so when i edit the action, i just edit 1 (and the left is same with parameter like counter...)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use like this:

```
void main()
{
   for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
     f(i);
}
```

and you f function can be implemented like this:

```
private void f(int i)
{
    var allButtons = Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
    allButtons.Single(x => x.Name.EndsWith(i.ToString())).Enabled = false;
}
```

or it can be like this too:

```
private void f(int i)
{
    var allButtons = Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
    allButtons[i].Enabled = false;
}
```

but take care you don exceeded from list range...

Comment: thanks for ur idea that we can find group of button by it name, i think it do same like reflect. My actual code bigger than example, like: fucntion f { buttonRead1.Enable = false; buttonWrite1.Enable = true; buttonEdit1.Enable = true; ......}. My 1st iead is make the list that pointer to all of the button, but maybe it not the best solution. I will use ur idea to edit my code again :D

Comment: Doing some thing you like, has many ways. you can find best way to do it. I hope I could help you...

Answer (score 0):

you can get all buttons with oftype extension method like this:

```
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.Enabled = true;
}
```

or use this:

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
     if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
     {
         //do stuff with control in form
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but that not all of button, just a group button name , my code just example

Comment: you can use button name to do it. I will leave you new answer now...

Comment: While it is sometimes acceptable to post multiple answers, I don't think it is warranted here because the key point of both of yours is retrieving the `Button` instances from the `Controls` property; the different ways of working with them after that are not significant enough to need their own answer.  Also, the two `foreach` loops shown here are _not_ equivalent; `if (control is Button)` would be analogous to `Control.OfType<Button>()`.

Comment: @BACON i dont understand much ur idea... but i use Jafar idea to do my project, i use find by name and linkq, set all the counter group of button i-true to true, and i-false to false, it will short code and easy to edit

Comment: @ThuyNguyen I understand that Jafar's idea worked for you.  I'm saying that both answers are the same basic idea and we don't need two answers with the same idea.  One answer with variations of the same idea is sufficient.  See [Are multiple answers by the same user acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251070/150605) and [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/699943).

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to answer his question on previous post, but comment was not a good place to write code. because of that I wrote a new answer. But next time I will not do that. Okay? @BACON

Comment: @Jafarashrafi You can always click the "edit" link at the bottom of your answer to add more information later or improve what you're already written.

Comment: Okay, thanx for your hint. I will do as you said... @BACON